# Retrieve SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON programmatically in SSMS for further analysis

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, query-tuning

When executing T-SQL queries via Management Studio, I can use `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` to capture statistics and query execution plan in a **nice-looking format as a text**.

How can I gather the query execution plan after I execute stored procedures, so that I can analyze it *programmaticaly* rather than analyze it visually in SSMS "messages" tab?

I can use `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` but I would like to see actual plan rather than estimated one, and it has same issue: How can get the outcome automatically?

I can also get XML plan from DMVs, but I wonder how can I get the text-formatted one.

I found [very similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008826/retrieve-set-statistics-io-and-set-statistics-time-values-via-ado-net) but it did not

here is an example of what I call "nice-looking text format":

 `|--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address].[AddressID]))
       |--Filter(WHERE:(STARTUP EXPR(suser_sname()=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(4000),[@2],0))))
       |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address].[IX_Address_StateProvinceID]))
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address].[PK_Address_AddressID]), SEEK:([AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address].[AddressID]=[AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address].[AddressID]),  WHERE:([AdventureWorks].[Person].[Address].[City]=N'Snohomish') LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)`