# How to get SQL server returned message?

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-express

If I use SQL Management Studio. When I create/drop tables, or do any updates, I can see messages like:

```
"Command(s) completed successfully."
"Cannot drop the table 'my_table', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."
```

But if I use python to execute the same query:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect('my connect options...') 
cursor = connection.cursor() 
my_result = cursor.execute('my create/drop table sql...') 
my_result = connection.commit()
```

I can see nothing from "my_result", "cursor" or "connection". Is the message generated by sql management studio? If not, and it is a sql server engine returned message, how to get this message?

Answer (score 2):

The messages displayed in the messages tab in SSMS are passed as InfoMessage events on the connection. Here's the C# API doco

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx

I'm not a python user so can't really help beyond pointing you at the documentation.

**Edit:**  This answer might help you [Getting SQL Server messages using ADO and win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872716/getting-sql-server-messages-using-ado-and-win32com)